# Maintaining the full state of a React app in the backend?

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, state

I'm building a real-time "lobby" type web app that hosts multiple users (2-8 at a time), where the state of the lobby is shared among the users. The UI is built with React. Each user establishes a websocket connection to the backend upon joining the lobby. At this time they receive the full global state of the app as a JSON object (its size should not exceed a few kilobytes).

I'm having difficulties conceptualizing the precise state maintenance scheme, and would like to hear your views about it, once I've described the situation in more detail.

The lobby presents to the users a number of finite resource pools, access to which is shared by everyone. The users will move these resources between each other as well as to and from the pools. My current thinking is that the full state of the lobby and all of its resource pools is stored and maintained **exclusively** in the backend. When a user wants to move a resource e.g. from a pool to themselves or vice versa, or to change the visible state of a resource, this is done with JSON messages sent over their respective websocket connections.

Each action they perform causes a message like this to be sent over the socket (simplified):

```
{
  "action": "MOVE",
  "source": "POOL1",
  "target": "user_id_here",
  ...metadata...
}
```

The users send these messages concurrently at arbitrary times and intervals, and the backend (using a Python asyncio-based server and a data store still to be determined) receives them serially, reconciles each one with the global state in the order they arrived, and then sends the **full updated state of the app** to **every user** over their websocket connections, for **every single message received**. The user who performed the action that triggered the state update additionally gets a status object informing them of a successful transaction, which the UI can then indicate to them.

When a user sends an action message that is impossible to reconcile (e.g. another user has exhausted a resource pool just before their message requesting a resource from that same pool came in), the app still sends them the full up-to-date state of the app, but a status object is included, containing information that the UI uses to inform them that their action could not be performed.

So far, so good. Given the types of actions, types of resource pools, number of users and size of state objects that are to be expected, the frequency of updates should not become a problem, neither in terms of resources nor bandwidth use.

To clarify: **none** of the actions that the users perform in the React UI mutate their local state in any way. Each and every action they perform is translated into a JSON message like the example above, and the result of that action will be receiving the updated full state of the app, which fully replaces the previous state that React used to render the UI with. The React-level app state is ephemeral, only used for rendering it once. All renders exclusively happen in response to state updates over websockets.

The one area that I'm having difficulties with is how to structure that ephemeral state on the React side so that rendering the updated state object is as quick and efficient as possible. I'm a backend guy and have no prior experience in building a React app of this nature (I last used it four years ago in a really ad-hoc manner, passing props to deeply nested child components, with state stored all over the place). I'm not quite sure what facilities and tools to use.

For example, I could use a top-level context provider with the useReducer hook, touted by many as a "Redux replacement" (which it technically isn't). Or, I could use Redux, but does it actually add any value in this case? Or something else?

Given that the whole state is replaced as a result of every action of every user, what is the best, most efficient, least render time-requiring way of structuring the React side of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you do not send in the entire state of each and every user over the network instead just send in the modification and let the individual users apps perform the change handling. Once you make this change you could make use.of redux and store the states in a reducer. Also doing this will help you avoid a lot of re-renders as the object references will not change for a lot of your components,

Another thing to add here is that you can store the redux state in the localStorage when the session is terminated

FurtherMore, the one problem that you could have here is that when the user re-connects, he might not get the changes that happened while he was online.

- To solve this, you can maintain a transaction id for each user so that the user is sent all the data post that transactionId till the current state by the server and then the app can process and update the transactions
- Or the other approach if to completely fetch the data when the user connects for first time or reconnects.

As far as using useReducer or Redux is concerned, you need to decide that based on the complexity of your App.

Cases where the app is small might easily be covered with useReducer and useContext but if you states are complex and you need to maintain multiple reducers, you should go ahead with Redux as it provides moree flexibility with data storage

**EDIT:**

If the only solution for you is to send the data totally to frontend and let the frontend render it, then you need to divide your frontend code into various simpler modules as much as possible so that no component is using a a complex state.

Once you do that you can make use of shouldComponentUpdate or areEqual parameter to a class component or functional component respectively.

The idea here is to compare the previous and current value that you get from props and let go ahead with the rendering logic or not.

You can store the state as it comes to a reducer inside the redux state, that way, you would be able to implement selectors that are memoized and are able to return data which doesn't change if the actual value hasn't change.

Also while you are using connect for your React app component, its actually a functional component, so unless mapStateToProps returns a value whose reference changes, it will prevent the re-render itself since its a PureComponent

I would strongly suggest, you go through the documentation of `shouldComponentUpdate`, `React.memo` and `redux`. Also look into **reselect** library that helps you implement memoized selectors

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is workable. For an action message `a`, `newstate = a(oldstate)`. I've decided to use Redis as the data store. A state change is often spread out over multiple data structures, representing the shared resource pools and other stateful things. In the backend, I'd have to generate a full diff between `oldstate` and `newstate` AND serialize that into a return message that can be used to update the local states. Always sending the full state is massively simpler; the problem domain is then just "how to most efficiently render in React". That's what I'm after.

Comment: With the edits, this is very solid advice. Thank you, I'll be looking into this.

Comment: @JKLaiho Glad to have helped